# Function can not return type with same interface as return type

Tags: c#, .net, interface

I have a simple program:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            InA testing = GetA();
        }

        static InA GetA<InA>()
        {
            return new A();
        }
    }

    public interface InA
    {
        void test();
    }

    public class A : InA
    {
        public void test()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

Why instance of A can not be returned from GetA()? A implements interface InA.

[image]

Comment: What's with the redundant generic type `GetA<InA>`? This means that in the scope of the method, `InA` refers to the generic type, not the interface. In the same way as interfaces should begin with the letter `I`,  as a convention, all generic types should start with the letter `T`, as in `TVal`. That way, it's obvious what you're dealing with.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

InA in that case is handled as [generic argument](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0zk36dx2.aspx) and not as interface name. You should declare your GetA method's generic argument differently or remove it at all. This should work:

```
static InA GetA()
{
    return new A();
}
```